# iOS browser scrolling bug

Tags: javascript, ios, css, reactjs, scroll

I'm having a vague bug while scrolling in a browser on an iOS device (iPad), it works 90% of the time but 10% it the scrolling is blocked. I then have to wait for a couple of seconds before it works again. This often happens after I've contracted/expanded a filter panel, which is also a scrollable component.

On all other devices, the scrolling is no issue whatsoever. I've looked everywhere on the internet but I couldn't find anyone with a similar problem?

My two scrollable components do have  `overflow-y: scroll` and 
`-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`, but in general I highly doubt it's a CSS issue as it works most of the time, just not at random times.

I have tried adding `onTouchStart={ () => {} }` to my component, but also that doesn't solve it.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by blocked? Are you completely unable to scroll for a few seconds as though the UI has frozen? or do you find that you have to scroll further at this point to then trigger the scroll to begin?

Comment: It's completely frozen, you can't scroll or touch anything for some seconds

Comment: Do you have any triggered code attached to the expansion of your filter panel that could be causing the delay?
I'm not sure I can help without seeing the code - is there any way you can replicate somewhere I/we can look?

Comment: If you could post someof your code it would be very helpful. Ever tried to fix the position (position: fixed;)?

Comment: @lydia Please share a way to replicate your issue or a temporal access to your app I recommend [Forward Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/forward-link-to-localhost/ghnicdmecgkdbledgnmbbnddfnjjgegp) , With that we can help you more

Comment: To me this sounds like maybe there are some memory consuming operations happening in the background. Have you checked if there is something like a looping JS function triggered when you scroll / toggle filters? Maybe an onScroll that should have a debounce?
I remember that iOS is pretty sparse with the memory it allocates for safari (at least they used to be).

As the others already stated, some more context to replicate might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across this bug before. It seems to arise when setting elements to be the height of the browser viewport (e.g., `height: 100vh`). Try setting this on your `<body>` element:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is still here in iOs15, and I developed a small fix and put it on GitHub.

Complete code here:
https://github.com/AlessandroCipolletti/fix-ios15-safari-scroll/blob/main/preventScrollBugsIfNeeded.ts

I noticed that the bug happens only when the scrollable content is "all on top" or "all at the end" of its scroll space.

I mean, when there is no scroll available in one of the two directions (top-bottom / left-right makes no difference for the occurrence of the bug).

So the idea is to check if this is the case during a `touchstart` event, and if so, make a 1px scroll by code.

I don't know why iOS "needs" this to make a proper scroll, but it works fine for me.

```
// do this inside a onTouchStart event handler:

const target = myScrollableContainer

// if it has vertical scroll
if (target.scrollHeight > target.clientHeight) {
  // if scroll is on top
  if (target.scrollTop === 0) {
    // move content 1px up
    target.scrollTop = 1
  } else 
  // if scroll in at the bottom
  if (target.scrollTop === (target.scrollHeight - target.clientHeight)) {
    // move content 1px down
    target.scrollTop = (target.scrollHeight - target.clientHeight) - 1
  }
}

// if it has horizontal scroll
if (target.scrollWidth > target.clientWidth) {
  // if scroll is at the beginning (left)
  if (target.scrollLeft === 0) {
    // move content 1px to the left
    target.scrollLeft = 1
  } else 
  // if scroll is at the end (right)
  if (target.scrollLeft === (target.scrollWidth - target.clientWidth)) {
    // move content 1px to the right
    target.scrollLeft = (target.scrollWidth - target.clientWidth) - 1
  }
}
```